# Is it necessary to run proprietry SSD optimizations in Windows 8 when using the "Optimize Drives" feature?

Tags: windows-8, ssd

The *Samsung Magician* software states the following in its *Performance Optimization* tab:

> If your current OS does not offer native TRIM support for SSDs, you
>   can use Magician to optimize performance as needed.

I take this to mean that this feature is redundant in Windows 8, at least when *Scheduled optimization* is turned on in Windows 8's *Optimize Drives*.

Intel's *SSD Optimizer does* not make a similar statement, is it safe to assume the same holds for it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Windows supports TRIM since Win7, there is no need (in terms of speed) of optimization software.

It is useful for features like secure erase though.

Source (and also many information about Windows & SSDs) is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx